# Backward and forward search are reversed with vi mode in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, vi

When I enter in vi mode with `set -o vi`, I enter in command mode, and I touch the key `?` it produces a `/` and the reverse. Is it normal? How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Weird. For me, `/` produces `/` and `?` produces `?`, as expected. I use it all the time! Some sort of shell option? Note that `/` searches for *earlier* history entries, which is sort of backwards if you visualize history entries listed in chronological order on successive lines but I think it turns out to be intuitive. All of the this applies equally to `zsh`, `bash`, and `ksh`.

Answer (score 0):

I added those keys :

```
bindkey -M vicmd '?' history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey -M vicmd '/' history-incremental-search-forward
```

I do as CTRL+R in emacs mode and I prefer